# Yelp Fusion API with R

Tags: r, api, for-loop, yelp

The Yelp Fusion API allows you to extract 50 rows at a time in R but you can loop through this by changing the off set.  If I use

```
  library(yelpr)
     Key <- ***
     NYC_Restaurants <- business_search(api_key = key,
                                    location = 'New York',
                                    term = "restaurants",
                                    offset = 0,
                                    limit = 50)
```

and keep incrementing the offset by adding 50 each time I can get all the data I want.  However I know there should be a way to write a loop.

I have tried

```
restaurant_function <- function(location, term){
    business_search(api_key = key,
                    location = location,
                    term = term,
                    offset = offset,
                   limit = 50)
                  }

NYC_Restaurants <- for (offset in seq(0,1000,50)) {
                        restaurant_function('New York','restaurants')
                        }
```

and it is just returning an empty set.  Any help and understanding of what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an API key so I'm not able to replicate this, but the document seems pretty clear: [Yelp business_search](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search)

I assume the issue is with your for-loop and you not supplying offset in the function.

```
key = "api_key"

restaurant_function <- function(key, location, term, offset){
  business_search(api_key = key,
                  location = location,
                  term = term,
                  offset = offset,
                  limit = 50)
}

NYC_Restaurants <- data.frame()

for (offset_val in seq(0,1000,50)) {
  temp <- restaurant_function(key, 'New York','restaurants', offset_val)
  NYC_Restaurants <- rbind(NYC_Restaurants, temp)
}

print(NYC_Restaurants)
```

You could also try setting offset as a global variable:

```
restaurant_function <- function(location, term){
  business_search(api_key = key,
                  location = location,
                  term = term,
                  offset = offset,
                  limit = 50)
}

NYC_Restaurants <- data.frame()

for (offset_val in seq(0,1000,50)) {
  offset <<- offset_val
  temp <- restaurant_function('New York','restaurants')
  NYC_Restaurants <- rbind(NYC_Restaurants, temp)
}

print(NYC_Restaurants)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I took your first suggestion and it is working on the iteration but R is returning a duplicate row.names error on the rbind.  Is there a way to make n+1 on the row names in each consecutive loop?  it goes from 1 to 50 and then does that again so it is trying to bind to data frames with the same row id which it will not allow.  I need it to go 51 to 100 on the second loop and so on.

Comment: Does business_search return a data frame? If so, try using `dplyr::bind_rows` or drop `row_id` before rbind by doing `temp <- restaurant_function('New York','restaurants') %>% select(-row_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Using creativename's function (thank you):

```
restaurant_function <- function(key, location, term, offset){
  business_search(api_key = key,
                  location = location,
                  term = term,
                  offset = offset,
                  limit = 50)
}
```

I worked with a colleague to get a loop that will return a 1000 results into a data frame:

```
NYC_Restaurants <- data.frame()

for (offset_val in seq(0,1000,50)) {
  print(offset_val)
  temp <- restaurant_function(key, 'New York', 'restaurants', offset_val) %>% 
    .$businesses %>% 
    mutate(categories = map(categories, flatten_chr)) %>% 
    mutate(categories = lapply(categories, paste, collapse = ", ") %>% unlist()) %>% 
    mutate(latitude = .$coordinates$latitude) %>% 
    mutate(longitude = .$coordinates$longitude) %>% 
    select(-coordinates) %>% 
    mutate(transactions = lapply(transactions, paste, collapse = ", ") %>% unlist()) %>% 
    mutate(address = .$location$display_address)  %>% 
    mutate(address = lapply(address, paste, collapse = ", ") %>% unlist()) %>% 
    select(-location)
  NYC_Restaurants <- bind_rows(NYC_Restaurants, temp)
}
```